# Const Strings Array in C

Tags: c, code-composer

I want to have a constant character array of which each array element to be passed to function in runtime. I have written them in following way:

```
const char *IntenistyVal[] ={"1","2","3","4","5"};
```

and The function is

```
Test(const char *pText)
```

(I cannot change this as this is one of standard Library function).
Now when I try to call the function "Test" as

```
Test(IntensityVal[0])
```

I also Tried

```
const char * const IntenistyVal[] ={"1","2","3","4","5"};
```

In both cases I am getting  error as "Expression must have a constant value".
Can Any one help me where I am doing Wrong.

Comment: Could it be the typo in the array declaration? `IntenistyVal` versus `IntensityVal`

Comment: You have an array of pointers-to-char there, not an array-of-char.

Comment: MSVC works perfectly fine after correcting the typo, assuming you wanted an array of strings and not a single string.

Comment: @ Mr Public: Sorry! Yup it is Typo

Comment: @Weather Vane:  Yes exactly I Need array of strings

Comment: The error messages dues to something else, you do not show us. `const char * strs[] = {"foo", "bar"}; void test(const char * p) {}; int main(void) {  test (strs[0]); return 0; }` is perfectly valid C.

Comment: That should not be a problem. See http://ideone.com/N6ZcYS.

Comment: @ alk: It works fine When I call Test as Test("Hello"); Does this is giving any clue?

Comment: @ R Sahu: Thanks But This is Not working for me in my compiler. I am using CCS (code composer studio) .

Comment: @alk: Sorry I am getting same error with your example too. Compiler is CCS for embedded platform.

Comment: Are you really using `= {"1","2","3","4","5"};` to initialise your pointer array, or could it be you are using variables instead of the literals (as you show here) inside your "real" code?

Comment: I am with @alk take a look at http://ideone.com/4Ybcxp

Comment: What line does the "Expression must have a constant value" refer to? Please post a small compilable complete program (with a main()) that causes the error message.

Comment: "Test(const char *pText)  ...  is one of standard Library function)" is unclear.  `Test()` is _not_ a standard library function.  Post its declaration.

Comment: Does `Test("Hello");` work?

Comment: This Is my actual Code:  Canvas(NeckIntensity,GFX_Panels + Intensity1, &MidBackIntensity, 0, &g_sKentec320x240x16_SSD2119, 75, 70, 20, 50,
       CANVAS_STYLE_TEXT | CANVAS_STYLE_TEXT_OPAQUE | CANVAS_STYLE_TEXT_VCENTER | CANVAS_STYLE_TEXT_HCENTER,
    0, 0, ClrWhite,&g_sFontCm18b,IntenistyVal[CurrIntensity.Neck], 0, 0);

Comment: This Is my actual Code:  1). Canvas(NIntensity,GFX_Panels + Intensity1, &MidIntensity, 0, &g_sKentec320x240x16_SSD2119, 75, 70, 20, 50,
       CANVAS_STYLE_TEXT | CANVAS_STYLE_TEXT_OPAQUE | CANVAS_STYLE_TEXT_VCENTER | CANVAS_STYLE_TEXT_HCENTER,
    0, 0, ClrWhite,&g_sFontCm18b,IntenistyVal[CurrIntensity.NInten], 0, 0);    2). const char * IntenistyVal[] ={"1","2","3","4","5"}; The Standard library I was talking about is Tiva C GrLib.

Comment: From Library: #define Canvas(sName, psParent, psNext, psChild, psDisplay, i32X, i32Y, i32Width,
               i32Height, ui32Style, ui32FillColor, ui32OutlineColor,    
               ui32TextColor, psFont, pcText, pui8Image, pfnOnPaint)       
        tCanvasWidget sName =
            CanvasStruct(psParent, psNext, psChild, psDisplay, i32X, i32Y,
                         i32Width, i32Height, ui32Style, ui32FillColor,
                         ui32OutlineColor, ui32TextColor, psFont, pcText,
                         pui8Image, pfnOnPaint)

Comment: Please add the code form the comments as an update to your question. As it stand its nod readable.

Answer (score 0):

A const array of char would be

```
 const char IntensityVal[] ={'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 0};
```

The final 0 is important if you want to pass it as a string. But I'm not sure if this is what you really want. It would help if you didn't hide the actual function as `Test`, but tell us the actual Standard Library function and what you want to achieve (i.e you have an [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: @ Jens: The example you presented implicits a constant sring .. But I need a array of constant strings

Comment: @Nagendra Babu: If you want an array of constant strings, you should say so in your question. Yet, for some reason you said that you want an array of characters.

Comment: @Jens: The standard Library is Tiva c Grlib. I want to initialize a Canvas widget text by pointing to elemnts of Array Rather than Hard coding it as it restricts my application.

Comment: @ AnT: Thanks. I mean to ask array of "constant character array"